$f_s := f \times \operatorname{id}_{\kappa(s)}$ is closed immersion $\Rightarrow $ $f^{\flat}_y \otimes id_{\kappa(s)}$ is surjective homomorphism.
Let $g : X\to S, h : Y\to S$ be proper $S$-schemes and  $f: X\to Y$  be an $S$-morphism. Let $s \in S$ be a point and let $f_s = f \times \operatorname{id}_{\kappa(s)} : g^{-1}(s)=X \otimes_S \kappa(s) \to h^{=1}(s) = Y \otimes_S \kappa(s)$ be the induced morphism of fibers. Let $f^{\flat}: \mathcal{O}_Y \to f_{*}\mathcal{O}_X$ be the morphism sheaves. $f_{*}\mathcal{O}_X$ can be an $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module of finite type.
My question is, if $f_s$ is a closed immersion, then $f^{\flat}_y \otimes \operatorname{id}_{\kappa(s)} : \mathcal{O}_{Y,y}/\mathfrak{m}_s \mathcal{O}_{Y,y} \to (f_{*}\mathcal{O}_X)_{y}/\mathfrak{m}_s\mathcal{O}_{Y,y} $ is a surjective homomorphism for all $y \in h^{-1}(s)$ ? If so, how can we show? What should we catch? This statment appears in the Gortz, Wedhorn, Algebraic Geometry, proof of Proposition 12.93. If needed, I will upload full proof. Can anyone help?
EDIT : Perhaps, $(f^{\flat}_s)_y = f^{\flat}_y \otimes\operatorname{id}_{\kappa(s)}$ is true? If so, then since $f_s$ is closed immersion, $(f^{\flat}_s)_y$ is surjective and we are done.
